# undefined al tomar valor de input

Tags: jquery, input

Estoy aprendiendo Jquery, sin embargo el siguiente codigo me retorna undefined en la consola:

```
$('#add_button').click(function(){
    console.log($('add_text').val());
});
```

y en HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="add_text"> <button id="add_button">Añadir</button>
```

Es para que la informacion que meta en el input al presionar el boton me l omuestre en la consola.
Pero no se porque me retorna undefined

Comment: Y cual es el `.val()` del boton añadir ??

Comment: Es un typo, te faltó indicar que es un id con el símbolo de `#` así: `'#add_text'`